# Timed (Cron-like) job in python at exact minute marks

Tags: python, cron

I want to run a process every minute, the problem is that my process takes some 5 seconds, therefore, if I schedule the job to run every minute it gets shifted by these 5 seconds every time.

So, this is what I have:

```
import schedule

def job():
    print("Date and time: " + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(5) # I only put this here to emulate my 5 second lasting process 

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have seen this solution from another post, but I would like to use a cron job better:

```
import time

while True:
    now = time.localtime()
    # Do what you need to do
    time.sleep(59 - now.tm_sec) #sleeps until roughly the next minute mark
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Also, what is this `schedule` module?  And does it actually have anything to do with `cron`?

Comment: Have you looked at [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: this gets so complicated if you want to have it on the exact second. What is the reason that you need to be so exact?

Comment: I want to run the process exactly every minute, not every minute+5 seconds that it lasts.

Comment: @ron.rothmanℝℝ, I looked at it but I thought it was too complicated for somiething in princpiple as easy as what I want, but I guess I'll have to look at it again, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @hansaplast it's just that i need it to run for a very long time (months maybe), and the reponse time from the servers vary quite a lot depending on their loads, so i might end up with very irregular time stamps

Comment: I recommend that you actually *use* **cron**, rather than trying to simulate it with other calls.  **cron** will start your job at the specified time; you would need to make special provisions to have it do otherwise (say, if the previous incarnation were still running).

Comment: why don't you just install a cron job which triggers the job every minute? So you get the regularity. Cron starts a script regardless on how much time it took for the script to execute

Comment: You are right that a cron outside the python script might be the cleanest way to go, so I might switch to that in the future. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manage the job from Python (and not through your system `cron` itself), then I suggest looking at [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Example:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from time import sleep

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

once_per_minute = CronTrigger('*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '0')
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

scheduler.start()

def my_func():
    print('hello!')

scheduler.add_job(my_func, trigger=once_per_minute)

sleep(180)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a misconception of cron.

If you install this cron job:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script.py
```

And you would do that in your script:

```
import datetime
import time

f = open('/tmp/cron_start_times.txt', 'a')
f.write("{}\n".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
time.sleep(5)
```

You would see from looking at `/tmp/cron_start_times.txt` that the script is *started* at first second of the minute. As others have said, you'd run into the issue that if your script takes longer than 60 seconds it would run 2 or more times in parallel. But if that is not an issue then you're fine with just doing the cron job.

Comment: Can I store python objects from one pass to the next in this way?

Comment: OP isn't actually using `cron`, he's asking about "cron"-like behaviour within his Python script.

Comment: I *thought* he is asking about cron, as he put `I would like to use a cron job better`. But never mind.

Comment: @Eudald: if you want to pass a python object from call to call then you *could* do it over pythons pickle/unpickle, but that's getting hacky. You're better off using rons solution if you want to do that